# Удаление символа в пустой строке, обработка исключений

Tags: java, android

Кнопка используется для удаление последнего символа в поле. Если поле пустое - происходит вылет.

```
case R.id.dell:

            try {


                String last = (String) textview.getText();
                textview.setText(last.substring(0, last.length() - 1));
            }
            catch ();
            break;
```

Какое исключение следует использовать для предотвращения вылета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ситуации с пустой строкой у вас будет вылет из-за выхода за пределы массива символов в строке. Вы можете просто проверять что строка не пустая или имеет достаточную длину перед обрезанием оной. Так вам не нужен будет `try-catch` блок. Например как-то так:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textview.getText().toString())) {
    //обрезаем строку
}
```

или так:

```
if (textview.getText().toString().length()!=0) {
    //обрезаем строку
}
```

Answer (score 1):

в общем случае

```
if (last != null && last.length() > 0) {
    textview.setText(last.substring(0, last.length() - 1)); 
 }
```

Comment: Собственно именно такую проверку делает [TextUtils#isEmpty(String str)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: я так и понял.. лучше уж по Оккаму )